# RxJava error handling in chain API calls

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

I have playing with Rxjava recently trying to implement a chain of events(Api callas/Database operations) and seem to have hit a roadblock when it comes to handling errors.

This is what I am trying to do. I am calling an Api that will check if user exists in the database. Based on the response I get, I am trying to chain a few sequences using rxjava. Following diagram might explain a little better.

```
                          checkUser()
                         /          \
                       No           Yes
                       /              \
            createUserRemote()       FetchUserNotesRemote()
                      |                    |
                    End               SaveUserNotesLocal()
                                            |
                                           End
```

I am able to chain together checkUser() -> FetchUserNotesRemote() -> SaveUserNotesLocal() sequence with the following code.

```
checkUser()
            .flatMap(id -> {return fetchData(id);})
            .flatMap(notesResponseObject -> {return saveFetchedData(notesResponseObject);})
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Integer integer) {
                    //handle onsuccess here
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    //handle errors here
                }
            });
```

The issue I am mainly trying to solve.

- I can't figure out how to handle a case where checkUser() returns
  a 404 http status. Because when that happens, subscriber's onError
  method gets called which seems to me is what should happen. How can I
  handle it so that when I get an error (404) response from API,
  instead of executing FetchUserNotesRemote() and SaveUserNotesLocal(),
  I execute a different chain of events?
- Another thing I am not sure about is, if there is an error called on
  any of the observables in a chain, how does the subscriber's onError method know
  which observable called it?

Answer (score 12):

1) To execute different chain of observables on error you can use method `onErorrResumeNext()`. More info here: [github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling-Operators)

Example:

```
checkUser().flatMap(id -> {return fetchData(id);})
           .flatMap(notesResponseObject -> {return saveFetchedData(notesResponseObject);})
           .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> { return doSomethingDifferent(); }
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
           .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Integer integer) {
                    //handle onsuccess here
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    //handle errors here
                }
            });
```

2) If the exception is thrown somewhere in your stream, it is passed down to subscriber `onError()`. If you want to know at which part of stream error was thrown, you can add multiple `onErorrResumeNext()` calls, that throw concrete exception after each api call.

```
    checkUser()
           .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> { return Observable.error(new CheckUserException()); }
           .flatMap(id -> {return fetchData(id);})
           .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> { return Observable.error(new FetchDataException()); }
           .flatMap(notesResponseObject -> {return saveFetchedData(notesResponseObject);})
           .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> { return Observable.error(new SaveDataException()); }
           .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
           .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
           .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Integer>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Integer integer) {
                    //handle onsuccess here
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    //handle errors here
                }
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try this out and let you know.

Comment: Hi @noob did you manage to get this working? I am also facing similar situation, the onErrorResumeNext method does not get called when the API timeout for me could you post the solution.

Comment: @Vie I posted an answer.

Comment: @Subayyal somehow onErrorResumeNext() is not called when I add it in the chain request.

Answer (score 0):

I completely forgot about this. But @mol pushed me in the right direction. My solution was a bit different. This may not be the best solution but it worked for me at the time.

I first created my own custom exception classes like following.

```
public class CreateUserLocalException extends Exception {
    public CreateUserLocalException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Then in my checkUser() function I throw exception of type I created above like following.

```
public Single<String> checkUser(String id) {
    return Single.create(new SingleOnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(SingleEmitter<String> emitter) throws Exception {
            try {
                GetUserResponseObject getUserResponseObject = apiClient.usersIdGet(id);
                Log.d("Test", "checkUserCall: Status: " + getUserResponseObject.getStatus());
                emitter.onSuccess(getUserResponseObject.getBody().getUserId());
            } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
                Log.d("Test", "AmazonServiceException : " + e.getErrorMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (e.getErrorMessage().equals("timeout")) {
                    throw new SocketTimeoutException();
                } else {
                    throw new CheckUserException(Integer.toString(e.getStatusCode()));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new CheckUserException(Integer.toString(AppConstants.ERROR));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Then in my chain of calls, in the event of an error, onError(throwable) gets invoked where I am checking the instanceof Exception to identify what kind of exception occurred. Below is the code for chain of functions.

```
cloudSyncHelper.checkUser(user.getUser_id())
        .retry(3, new Predicate<Throwable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean test(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                Log.d("Test", throwable.toString());
                if (throwable instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                    Log.d("Test", "Time out.. Retrying..");
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        })
        .flatMap(s -> {
            return cloudSyncHelper.createUserLocal(user)
                    .onErrorResumeNext(throwable -> {
                        Log.d("Test", "onErrorResumeNext, throwable message: " + throwable.getMessage());
                        if (throwable instanceof CreateUserLocalException) {
                            if (Integer.parseInt(throwable.getMessage()) == AppConstants.LOCAL_DB_DUPLICATE) {
                                return Single.just(user.getUser_id());
                            }
                        }
                        return Single.error(new CreateUserLocalException(Integer.toString(AppConstants.LOCAL_DB_ERROR)));
                    });
        })
        .flatMap(id -> {
            return cloudSyncHelper.fetchData(id)
                    .retry(3, new Predicate<Throwable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean test(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                            Log.d("Test", throwable.toString());
                            if (throwable instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                                Log.d("Test", "Time out.. Retrying..");
                                return true;
                            }
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
        })
        .flatMap(notesResponseObject -> {
            return cloudSyncHelper.saveFetchedData(notesResponseObject);
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Integer integer) {
                //handle onsuccess here
                googleSignInButton.setEnabled(true);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Log.d("Test", "onSuccess Called");
                getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.AppName, MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).apply();
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginScreen.this, HomeScreen.class));
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

                if (e instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
                    googleSignInButton.setEnabled(true);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Log.d("Test", "Socket Time Out");
                    Utils.createToast(LoginScreen.this, "Socket timed out");
                    return;
                }

                int code = Integer.parseInt(e.getMessage());
                Log.d("Test", "onError Called");
                if (e instanceof CheckUserException) {
                    Log.d("Test", "onError CheckUserException");
                    if (code == AppConstants.NOTFOUND) {
                        newUserSequence(user);
                    } else {
                        googleSignInButton.setEnabled(true);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Utils.createToast(LoginScreen.this, "Unable to user information from cloud. Try again.");
                    }
                }
                if (e instanceof CreateUserLocalException) {
                    Log.d("Test", "onError CreateUserLocalException");
                    googleSignInButton.setEnabled(true);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                if (e instanceof FetchDataException) {
                    Log.d("Test", "onError FetchDataException");
                    if (code == AppConstants.NOTFOUND) {
                        googleSignInButton.setEnabled(true);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.AppName, MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).apply();
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginScreen.this, HomeScreen.class));
                    } else {
                        googleSignInButton.setEnabled(true);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Log.d("Test", "Unable to fetch data from cloud");
                        Utils.createToast(LoginScreen.this, "Unable to fetch data from cloud. Try again.");
                    }
                }
                if (e instanceof SaveDataLocalException) {
                    googleSignInButton.setEnabled(true);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Log.d("Test", "onError SaveDataLocalException");
                    if (code == AppConstants.LOCAL_DB_ERROR) {
                        Log.d("Test", "Unable to save data fetched from cloud");
                        Utils.createToast(LoginScreen.this, "Unable to save data fetched from cloud");
                    } else {
                        Utils.createToast(LoginScreen.this, "Unable to save data fetched from cloud");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps.